# Docker Compose ports are being ignored on up

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

This is my Docker Compose file containing 4 api containers:

```yaml
version: '3.4'

services:
  api1.api:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}api1
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Api1.Api/Dockerfile
    networks: 
    - dev-network
    ports:
    - "62000:443"
    - "62001:80"

  api2.api:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}api2
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Api2.Api/Dockerfile
    networks: 
    - dev-network
    ports:
    - "62002:443"
    - "62003:80"


  api3.api:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}api3
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Api3.Api/Dockerfile
    networks: 
    - dev-network
    ports:
    - "62004:443"
    - "62005:80"


  api4.api:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}api4
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Api4.Api/Dockerfile
    networks: 
    - dev-network
    ports:
    - "62006:443"
    - "62007:80"
networks:
  dev-network:
      name: dev-network
```

I have set the ports but when I run docker-compose up -d, the results are that either 1 or 2 of the apis will have the specified ports only. The rest will be randomly generated or even blank.

I have to manually restart that container before it generates a random port.

Am I missing a command or step? How can I get my docker-compose to follow the ports that have been set?

Comment: With the currently given information, [I can't reproduce your issue](https://gist.github.com/zeitounator/f8cc176a983052caa18ef73d5aa60f83)

Comment: Hello @Zeitounator, what other information should I give?

Comment: For the ports example is if api1 is supposed to start and have the port 62000, it starts with 52888 instead. Sometimes it will randomly have 62000 but I cant seem to control when it happens.

Comment: `what other information should I give` <= a complete [mcve](/help/mcve) as I tried to provide in my reproduce link would be a good start.